# Get names based on another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get the first and last names of people who work in HR department.

```
    FirstName   LastName        Year    Department
83  Joe         Faulk           2       Austin Public Library
84  Bryce       Benton          5       HR
85  Sarah       Cronin          7       Austin Public Library
86  Gabriel     Montgomery      2       Austin Resource Recovery
87  Patricia    Genty-Andrade   3       HR
```

This is my code it shows me error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'

```
names = df.iloc[:, 0:4][df['Department'] == 'HR'].unique()
```

I need the output to be like this

```
   FirstName   LastName        Department
0  Joe         Faulk           HR
1  Bryce       Benton          HR
2  Sarah       Cronin          HR
3  Gabriel     Montgomery      HR
4  Patricia    Genty-Andrade   HR
```

Comment: Why do you need unique?
Isn't `df[df['Department'] == 'HR'][["FirstName", "LastName", "Department"]]` working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `drop_duplicates` instead of `unique`, as `unique` is for Series.

```
df.loc[df['Department'] == 'HR',
       ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Department']].drop_duplicates()
```